# A bytes-like object is required, not 'Tensor' when calling map on string tensors in eager mode

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to use TF.dataset.map to port over this old code because I get a deprecation warning.

Old code which reads a set of custom protos from a TFRecord file:

```py
record_iterator = tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator(path=filename)
for record in record_iterator:
    example = MyProto()
    example.ParseFromString(record)
```

I am trying to use eager mode and map, but I get this error.

```py
def parse_proto(string):
      proto_object = MyProto()
      proto_object.ParseFromString(string)
```

```py
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(dataset_paths)
parsed_protos = raw_tf_dataset.map(parse_proto)
```

This code works:

```py
for raw_record in raw_tf_dataset:                                                                                                                                         
    proto_object = MyProto()                                                                                                                                              
    proto_object.ParseFromString(raw_record.numpy())
```

But the map gives me an error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'Tensor'
```

What is the right way to take use the argument the function results of the map and treat them like a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to extract string form the tensor and use in the `map` function. Below are the steps to be implemented in the code to achieve this.

1. You have to decorate the map function with `tf.py_function(get_path, [x], [tf.float32])`. You can find more about tf.py_function [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_function). In `tf.py_function`, first argument is the name of `map` function, second argument is the element to be passed to `map` function and final argument is the return type.
2. You can get your string part by using `bytes.decode(file_path.numpy())` in map function.

So modify your program as below,

```
parsed_protos = raw_tf_dataset.map(parse_proto)
```

to

```
parsed_protos = raw_tf_dataset.map(lambda x: tf.py_function(parse_proto, [x], [function return type]))
```

Also modify `parse_proto` as below,

```
def parse_proto(string):
      proto_object = MyProto()
      proto_object.ParseFromString(string)
```

to

```
def parse_proto(string):
      proto_object = MyProto()
      proto_object.ParseFromString(bytes.decode(string.numpy()))
```

In the below simple program, we are using `tf.data.Dataset.list_files` to read path of the image. Next in the `map` function we are reading the image using `load_img` and later doing the `tf.image.central_crop` function to crop central part of the image.

**Code -**

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array, array_to_img
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def load_file_and_process(path):
    image = load_img(bytes.decode(path.numpy()), target_size=(224, 224))
    image = img_to_array(image)
    image = tf.image.central_crop(image, np.random.uniform(0.50, 1.00))
    return image

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files('/content/bird.jpg')
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(lambda x: tf.py_function(load_file_and_process, [x], [tf.float32]))

for f in train_dataset:
  for l in f:
    image = np.array(array_to_img(l))
    plt.imshow(image)
```

**Output -**

[image]

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.

Comment: @Kartik Ayyar - Hope we have answered your question. Can you please accept and upvote the answer if you are satisfied with the answer.